# Url redirecting in ASP.NET MVC 4 Mobile application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 Mobile application, in which I am trying to redirect to an external website. However its failing with "Error loading page" message.

```
public void RedirectToGoogle()
{
    Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
}
```

Also I see the following script in _Layout.cshtml which is created automatically while creating the application.

```
<script>
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
       // As of Beta 2, jQuery Mobile's Ajax navigation does not work in all cases (e.g.,
       // when navigating from a mobile to a non-mobile page, or when clicking "back"
       // after a form post), hence disabling it.
       $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
   });
</script>
```

I tried changing $.mobile.ajaxEnabled to true, but no success.

Any thoughts on how to do url redirecting in ASP.NET MVC 4 Mobile application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response.Redirect is for WebForms and uses the WebForms page lifecycle. For MVC you should use  return Redirect("http://www.bing.com");

I've reproduced the problem on ASP.NET MVC 4/Beta with a mobile project. It's a CORS  (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) issue. See http://www.webdavsystem.com/ajax/programming/cross_origin_requests

Use the F12 developer tools to Fiddler to see the problem.

EC7118: XMLHttpRequest for http://www.bing.com/ required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). 
localhost:52137

SEC7119: XMLHttpRequest for http://www.bing.com/ required CORS preflight. 
localhost:52137

Comment: What is the solution? I am getting the below errors: SEC7118: XMLHttpRequest for https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KcdPEYjmvemndMfJv3IAIK5HAX2xs267mvtt6WHGkC8/edit?usp=sharing required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).   SEC7119: XMLHttpRequest for https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KcdPEYjmvemndMfJv3IAIK5HAX2xs267mvtt6WHGkC8/edit?usp=sharing required CORS preflight.      SEC7120: Origin http://localhost:18591 not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.     SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.